# Rational Number Form

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory

I was reading *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves by Silverman and Tate* and they state:

Every non-zero rational number may be uniquely written in the form $\frac{m}{n}p^v$, where $m,n$ are integers prime to $p,n>0$ and the fraction $m/n$ is in lowest terms. Then 
$$
\text{ord}\left(\frac{m}{n} p^v \right)=v
$$

However, it offers no example of this and I can't see how such a representation is unique. For example, if the integer was $13$, then $m=n=1$ and $p=13,v=1$. However, if the integer was $10$, we have
$$
\frac{2}{1}5^1
$$
as a possible representation and we also have
$$
\frac{5}{1}2^1
$$
The problem is even worse with non-integer rationals
$$
\frac{15}{7}=\frac{3}{7}5^1=\frac{5}{7}3^1=\frac{15}{1}7^{-1}
$$
as there is also no statement on $v$. Is it intended that $v$ be negative? Even if that is the case, then we still have 
$$
\frac{1}{10}=\frac{1}{2}5^{-1}=\frac{1}{5}2^{-1}
$$
and the representation is not unique. I checked the errata and it makes no mention of error here. So what have I misinterpreted?

Comment: Here the prime $p$ is *fixed*, not variable.

Comment: @BillDubuque But then how would that work? If I took $p=5$ then wanted to represent $13$, I would have $\frac{m}{n}\cdot 5^v$ and there's no combination that works that keeps $m,n$ integers prime to $p$. At least not that I'm seeing.

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm sorry but I still don't see that fixes the example I gave in my previous comment, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ still doesn't allow a combination with $p=5$. Again, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Sure there is: $\, 13\,=\,\frac{13}1\cdot 5^{0}\ \ $

Comment: It's page 49, and they say "so we let $p$ be some prime..." meaning some *fixed* prime. Is everything clear now?

Comment: @BillDubuque Of course! It would be something horribly obvious! I was fixated on the fact that I was assuming they intended $v>0$ when they began to talk about 'order'. Thank yo so much for clearing this up! I stared at this for some time wondering what they could mean. You should copy any of your comments as an answer! You certainly deserve credit for clearing this up so quickly and efficiently!

Comment: Don't sweat it - that's a common type of oversight that probably everybody makes at one time or another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the prime $\,p\,$ is *fixed*, not variable. Indeed they write on p. 49 "so we let $p$ be some prime...".

If $\,p\nmid a,b\,$ then said unique rep of $\ t =\dfrac{a}b\ $ is $\ \dfrac{a}b\cdot p^{\large \color{#c00}0},\,$ so $\ v_p(t) = \color{#c00}0.$